# More than 1 graph with JUnit result on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

Do you know how can we have more than one graph displaying JUnit tests results with Jenkins?

In the main view of the Jenkins job, I have one graph displaying all tests results (tests pass, fails, etc...). But this Jenkins job achieves tests of differents modules of a programm. Is it possible having one graph per module?

Maybe the solution is in format of the xml result file with JUnit syntax?

Many thanks

Comment: the graph I believe is displayed using a plugin. Could you check if that plugin supports multiple display. Data wise you can always generate test data per module.

Comment: It's JUnit plugin, and documentation are very light. I see nothing in website [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JUnit+Plugin) talking about possibility of multiple display. Is there another more precise website for this plugin?

Comment: On other note, the data is anytime available so you can evaluate the data for the entire project and click on the graph to get package wise details of the tests execution at present as well. Just that I don't see multiple graphs option to display that data differently.

Answer (score 1):

The JUnit plugin will aggregate, that's the way it is written. So, no you can't, not currently.